# Splitting Columns that contains delimiters using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, split

i am an incoming file with 100+ columns where in some columns we have comma separated values.
i have to convert those delimited columns in to multiple columns with same column header and its sequence.

for ex..if my input is below..

name,age,interests,sports,gender,year
aaa,44,"movies,poker","tennis,baseball",M,2000
bbb,23,"movies","hockey,baseball",F,2018

output should be..we should not hardcode the column names..which ever column has , it should be split.

name,age,interests_1,interest_2,sports_1,sports_2,gender,year
aaa,  44,movies,     poker,     tennis,   baseball,M,    2000
bbb,  23,movies,                hockey,   baseball,F,    2018

Comment: Could you please add the code that you have already to solve the task (even if it is incomplete or doesn't work)? Also if you are using a framework or lib, please mention this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use these columns as columns of the file you are going to create:-

```
st = '''name,age,interests,sports,gender,year aaa,44,"movies,poker","tennis,baseball",M,2000 bbb,23,"movies","hockey,baseball",F,2018'''
columns = st.split(',')

>>columns
['name',
 'age',
 'interests',
 'sports',
 'gender',
 'year aaa',
 '44',
 '"movies',
 'poker"',
 '"tennis',
 'baseball"',
 'M',
 '2000 bbb',
 '23',
 '"movies"',
 '"hockey',
 'baseball"',
 'F',
 '2018']
```